# QInputDialog: OK and CANCEL Buttons: Removing button images for OK and Cancel

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qinputdialog

In QInputDialog how do I get rid of the icons in the OK and Cancel buttons?

[image]

Notice the the icons for cancel and ok. I looked through the properties button couldn't figure out how to remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strategy of the solution is to first obtain the buttons, but these belong to a `QDialogButtonBox`, so you must use the `findChild()` method, then reset the icons, there is only one problem, that the buttons are created when necessary, for example when it is visible or when you change the `okButtonText` or `cancelButtonText`. For example in the we can force it by making it visible.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QInputDialog>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QAbstractButton>
#include <QDialogButtonBox>

static int getInt(QWidget *parent,
                  const QString &title,
                  const QString &label,
                  int value=0,
                  int min=-2147483647,
                  int max=2147483647,
                  int step=1,
                  bool *ok=nullptr,
                  Qt::WindowFlags flags=Qt::Widget)
{
    QInputDialog dialog(parent, flags);
    dialog.setWindowTitle(title);
    dialog.setLabelText(label);
    dialog.setIntRange(min, max);
    dialog.setIntValue(value);
    dialog.setIntStep(step);
    dialog.setVisible(true);
    for(QAbstractButton *btn:  dialog.findChild<QDialogButtonBox*>()->buttons()){
        btn->setIcon(QIcon());
    }
    int ret = dialog.exec();
    if (ok)
        *ok = !!ret;
    if (ret) {
        return dialog.intValue();
    } else {
        return value;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    bool ok;
    int res = getInt(nullptr, "Factorial Calc", "Factorial of:", 5, 0, 100, 1, &ok);
    if(ok)
        qDebug()<< res;
    return 0;
}
```

But if you use static methods like `QInputDialog::getInt()` we will not be able to access the `QInputDialog` directly, we have to do it a moment after showing the `QInputDialog` with a `QTimer`, so there are 2 cases:

- A parent is passed to the static method:

---

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QInputDialog>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QAbstractButton>
#include <QDialogButtonBox>
#include <QTimer>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget widget;
    bool ok;
    QTimer::singleShot(0, [&widget](){
        QInputDialog *dialog = widget.findChild<QInputDialog *>();
        for(QAbstractButton *btn:  dialog->findChild<QDialogButtonBox*>()->buttons()){
            btn->setIcon(QIcon());
        }
    });
    int res = QInputDialog::getInt(&widget, "Factorial Calc", "Factorial of:", 5, 0, 100, 1, &ok);
    if(ok)
        qDebug()<< res;
    return 0;
}
```

- A parent is not passed to the static method:

---

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QInputDialog>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QAbstractButton>
#include <QDialogButtonBox>
#include <QTimer>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget widget;
    bool ok;
    QTimer::singleShot(0, [](){
        for(QWidget *widget: QApplication::topLevelWidgets()){
            if(QInputDialog *dialog = qobject_cast<QInputDialog*>(widget)){
                for(QAbstractButton *btn:  dialog->findChild<QDialogButtonBox*>()->buttons()){
                    btn->setIcon(QIcon());
                }
            }
        }
    });
    int res = QInputDialog::getInt(nullptr, "Factorial Calc", "Factorial of:", 5, 0, 100, 1, &ok);
    if(ok)
        qDebug()<< res;
    return 0;
}
```